# Why does SWT Edge browser stuck on browser.evaluate()?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, webview2

all! Asking for your help.
I'm pretty new to SWT - so please do not judge me strictly for questions.

I have a big/old RCP app. It has many views that use embedded browser.
Recently made 2 major updates:

1. Updated Eclipse platform from **3.7.2** to **4.21**;
2. switch from **IE** to **Edge** browser;

The package that I'm using has version:

> org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64
>
> Bundle-Version: 3.117.0.v20210906-0842

**OS:** Windows 10

### Problem:

After clicking the button on embedded browser page, JavaScript calls the Java `MyFunction extends BrowserFunction`. Which prepares the data to refresh the page. And before refresh it calls **browser.evaluate()** to get some number from JS side:

```
Double numberFromJS = (Double) browser.evaluate("return 2+2; //this expression just for example")
```

The main thread stuck in the `while` loop, because `pstr[0] == null` always `true`.

```
package org.eclipse.swt.browser;

class Edge extends WebBrowser {
    
    ...
    
    static int callAndWait(String[] pstr, ToIntFunction<IUnknown> callable) {
        int[] phr = new int[1];
        IUnknown completion = newCallback((result, pszJson) -> {
            phr[0] = (int)result;
            if ((int)result == COM.S_OK) {
                pstr[0] = wstrToString(pszJson, false);
            }
            return COM.S_OK;
        });
        pstr[0] = null;
        phr[0] = callable.applyAsInt(completion);
        completion.Release();
        Display display = Display.getCurrent();
        while (phr[0] == COM.S_OK && pstr[0] == null) { // <-------------- here
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
        }
        return phr[0];
    }

}
```

### investigation:

1. Here [https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#:%7E:text=run%20synchronously.%20Calling-,evaluate(),-and%20getText()%20from) I found a limitation about Edge and evaluate, but there is no `Exception` throwed;
2. Tried to debug the `display.readAndDispatch()`, but there is lack of java docs and it jumps into native methods - not clear for me what should exactly happen.
   As I understood in general it should handle message from OS and pass it into `completion` callback from above and set some value into `pstr[0]`;
3. interesting observation - the `evaluate()` method for this browser is successfully passed just on it creation. Looks like it became broken after something.

### Questions:

1. Any suggestion to pay attention/check some places?
2. Is there known issues for that method and workarounds for it?
3. Is it possible that the messages from system are intercepted from some other place?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=578017) just says evaluate gets stuck if called in a BrowserFunction, it doesn't mention throwing an exception.

Comment: Possibly the Chromium browser would work for you, instructions for that are in the FAQ you reference.

Comment: Thank you @greg-449 for such quick reply. 
I will try workaround from the "bug".  But still wondering why that evaluate not working at this moment. 

And Is there better way to solve it without wrapping into callback all that I need to invoke in sync after 'evaluate()'?